# How many prime numbers C program

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, primes, function-definition

I wrote this program to find prime numbers between 1 and 50000, and I still need to find how many prime numbers there is (I tried a lot of tricks but I did not succeed)

```
#include <stdio.h>

//int getValueFromUser();
void PrintListOfPrime(int value);

int main() {
    int value = 23;
    PrintListOfPrime(value);
    return 0;
}

void PrintListOfPrime(int value) {
    int  ValueIsPrime; //ValueIsPrime is used as flag variable

    printf("The list of primes: ");

    for (int i = 2; i <= value; i++) {
        ValueIsPrime = 1;
        /* Check if the current number i is prime or not */
        for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
            /*
             * If the number is divisible by any number
             * other than 1 and self then it is not prime
             */

            if (i % j == 0) {
                ValueIsPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        /* If the number is prime then print */
        if (ValueIsPrime == 1)
            printf("%d, ", i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: If you're able to list the primes, can't you just increment a counter instead of printing said prime?

Comment: "I tried a lot of tricks but I did not succeed" is vague.  How did it fail to succeed?

Comment: @Chouiba Zahira There are  5133 prime numbers up to 50000.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried a lot of tricks but I did not succeed

If OP's code takes too long to ran, iterate to the square root of `i`, not up to `i/2`.

`j <= i / 2` is very slow.  Use `j <= i / j` instead.

---

Form a count and increment with every prime. [@gspr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63012223/how-many-prime-numbers-c-program#comment111429278_63012223)

```
if (ValueIsPrime == 1) {
  printf("%d, ", i);
  prime_count++;
}
```

---

Bigger change yet even faster to "find prime numbers between 1 and 50000", research [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 0):

Hello fast answer is to create a variable in main, int totaleOfPrimes = 0; for example.
then send it by reference to the fucntion :

1. Function declaration :  void PrintListOfPrime(int value,int* counter);
2. Function call : void PrintListOfPrime(value,&totaleOfPrimes);
   then Increment counter befor printing :

```
if (ValueIsPrime == 1){
   (*counter)++;
   printf("%d, ", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate the loops for all numbers between 2 and value. You should consider only 2 and odd numbers.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline size_t PrintListOfPrime( unsigned int n ) 
{
    size_t count = 0;

    printf( "The list of primes:\n" );

    for ( unsigned int i = 2; i <= n; i = i != 2 ? i + 2 : i + 1 ) 
    {
        int isPrime = 1;
        /* Check if the current number i is prime or not */
        for ( unsigned int j = 3; isPrime && j <= i / j; j += 2 ) 
        {
            /*
             * If the number is divisible by any number
             * other than 1 and self then it is not prime
             */

            isPrime = i % j != 0;
        }

        /* If the number is prime then print */
        if ( isPrime )
        {
            if ( ++count % 14 == 0 ) putchar( '\n' ); 
            printf( "%u ", i );
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int n = 50000;

    size_t count = PrintListOfPrime( n );
    
    printf( "\n\nThere are %zu prime numbers up to %u\n", count, n );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this code in C. It will return the value of a pi(x) function. It is basically the Prime counting function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEAST_PRIME 2
#include <math.h>

int main() //works for first 10000 primes.
{
int lower_limit = 2, no_of_sets;
// printf("NUMBER OF SETS: ");
// scanf("%d", &no_of_sets);

int remainder, divisor = 2, remainder_dump, upper_limit; //upper limit to be specified 
                                                         //by user.
int i = 1;
// printf("SPECIFY LOWER LIMIT: ");
// scanf("%d", &lower_limit);
int number_to_be_checked = lower_limit;
printf("SPECIFY UPPER LIMIT: ");
scanf("%d", &upper_limit);

printf("2\t\t\t\t", number_to_be_checked);
//PRINTS 2.*/
do
{
    remainder_dump = 1;
    divisor = 2;

    do
    {
        remainder = number_to_be_checked % divisor;
        if (remainder == 0)
        {
            remainder_dump = remainder_dump * remainder; // dumping 0 for rejection.
            break;
        }
        ++divisor;

    } while (divisor <= number_to_be_checked / divisor); // upto here we know number 
is prime or not.
    if (remainder_dump != 0)
    {
        ++i;
        printf("%d.\t\t\t\t", number_to_be_checked); //print if prime.
    };
    number_to_be_checked = number_to_be_checked + 1;
} while (number_to_be_checked <= upper_limit);
printf("\n                                    pi(x) = %d \n", i);
//printf("pi function value is %f.", (i - 1) / (log(i - 1)));
float app;
app = upper_limit / (log(upper_limit));
float plot_value;
plot_value = (i) / app;
printf("                                    BETA FUNCTION VALUE ~ %f", plot_value);
return 0;
}
```